# Function add_compression_policy not found with TimescaleDB

Tags: timescaledb

I am running the latest version of TimescaleDB.

In the docs I found this: https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression#quick-start

When I run:

```sql
CREATE TABLE con_details (LIKE deprecated_consumption_details INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES);
    
SELECT create_hypertable('con_details', 'date');
    
ALTER TABLE con_details SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'meter_id'
);
    
SELECT add_compression_policy('con_details', INTERVAL '7 days');
```

the last line is throwing an error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function add_compression_policy(unknown, interval) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 9
```

Also other functions that are in the docs such as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM hypertable_detailed_size('con_details');
```

are giving me errors:

```
ERROR: function hypertable_detailed_size(unknown) does not exist
```

The TimescaleDB extension is of course enabled (creating and querying a Hypertable works fine...)

Comment: Which version of TimescaleDB do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, [`add_compression_policy`](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#add_compression_policy) is in the API of TimescaleDB 2.0, while earlier versions, e.g., 1.7.4 have [`add_compress_chunks_policy`](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.7/api#add_compress_chunks_policy). And [`hypertable_detailed_size`](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#hypertable_size) doesn't exist prior 2.0.

TimescaleDB 2.0, which is the latest release since December 21, introduces number of [breaking changes in its API](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/release-notes/changes-in-timescaledb-2) and policies are affected considerably. For example, `add_compress_chunks_policy` is renamed into `add_compression_policy` and its arguments are renamed too.

[The documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/main) shows latest API by default, while many users are likely to use 1.7, which requires to use [different version of documentation](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.7/main).
Timescale docs page allow to chose a version of documentation corresponding to major TimescaleDB version:

[image: Documnetation versions]

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I was under the impression that I was using v2.0.0 which the AMI on AWS stated (TimescaleDB 2.0.0 (PostgreSQL 12) - Ubuntu 18.04 (EBS Backed) - ami-06479c10b25555960).  Unfortunately it's v1.7.4.   Why this is the case is another problem not related to this question though.